# Update-database command failed to create database

Tags: asp.net, localdb

So I'm studying Entity Framework Core through the course I am following to. So in the video he run the **update-database** command and it went smoothly, well it is the opposite when I tried the command. I already done the add-migration then just need to execute the update-database commaand.

Here's the error.log: [Error Log Link](https://gist.github.com/nullstrike/22594fe597faa116d89e060088508189)

I have some idea that it is because of my userprofile that I get this error since it contains spaces.

Anyways here the error message I get from the package manager console:

> Error Number:5123,State:1,Class:16
>
> CREATE FILE encountered operating
> system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create
> the physical file 'C:\Users\Infinite RegressionAngelShop.mdf'.
>
> CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check
> related errors.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't solved this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update MSSql to the latest version. It worked for me.